# Looping through JavaScript elements in Swift, WKWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, webkit

I'm trying to loop through the multiple 'name' class objects in the html of a website by injecting JavaScript into a `WKWebView`. How could this loop be achieved? I have the following code snippet in my app:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('name')", completionHandler: { (value, error) in
    print(value)
})
```

Printing `value` gives me nil.

Comment: I'm not really sure as I haven't written much in swift, but shouldn't you just add a `return` before `document.getElementsByClassName('name')`? Like `return document.getElementsByClassName('name')`.

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński I think we have to use the evaluateJavaScript function to work with strings of Java script code – I'm not sure returning in that way is possible

Comment: a shitty approach would be to assign an id to each element. so you could loop through the id's.   `for (var i=0;i<your_dependency;i++) { console.log(document.getElementById("yourId"+[i]).value);  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution I found was to use [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna), an HTML parser for iOS that allows you to loop over css nodes.